# Problems in generating random linearly independent binary vectors

Tags: c, random, vector

I'm trying to continuously generate a sequence of random linearly independent binary vectors, each contain 1024 elements 0 or 1. I need generate 1024 (which is also the maximum I can get) such vectors. Here is the basic idea of what I did

```
srand( (unsigned) time(NULL) );
while(obtained <= 1024)
{
    for (int i=0;i<1024;i++)
        vector[i] = rand() % 2;

    check linear indepence against previously stored linearly independent vectors

    if (linearly independent)
        store it;
        obtained += 1;
    else
        discard;
 }
```

However, it seems that the code can only generate 527 linear indpendent vectors here, which is quite odd. I found that it might be the issue of random number generator, because if I put srand() in the loop, i.e., before each rand() execution, it is able to finish generating 1024 such vectors. However, the program will be very slow.

Also, it is interesting that if I want to generate 1024 1024-dimenional random linearly independent vectors consisting of elements chosen from Galois field GF(4) or higher, rather than the binary field, the above code segment works fine.

Note that the linear independence here are in terms of operations in the finite field.

Can anybody help explain the possible reasons and suggest some directions to look at? Thanks sincerely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're using a C library with a low-quality implementation of `rand`. The implementation in MSVC's CRT is notoriously bad, for example.

What you're doing is actually very similar to a common statistical test that measures the quality of random number generators. The *ranks of matrices* test creates random binary matrices, computes their rank, and tests whether the distribution of ranks matches the expected distribution. Essentially, your code fails to create a full-rank binary matrix.

You could either use a better RNG (maybe from a third-party library) or try one the following:

- Use a different bit of the value returned by `rand`.
- Call `rand` again after a certain number of iterations and discard the value. Since 1024 is a power of two, this might be the cause for some kind of repetition in the random values.
- Use more bits from a single invocation of `rand`. Make sure to check the value of RAND_MAX on your system.

Comment: Actually I'm working in Linux environment, so the standard C library is used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to say that I have solved the problem by using the RNG in GNU Scientific Library (GSL). Now the `gsl_rng_mt19937` RNG is used in place of the unix standard rand().